# Which perl module to use to write tests with selenium?

Tags: perl, selenium, testing

We have site and want to write test. We decide to use Selenium.

May someone advice which modules to use? Are they work with recent versions of selenium? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: One worth looking at is [Test::BDD::Cucumber](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-BDD-Cucumber). Talk to the community around that module for how they integrate with Selenium/webdriver/etc.  Maybe [here](https://gitter.im/pjlsergeant/test-bdd-cucumber-perl).

Answer (score 1):

Did you look on CPAN? [Test::WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::WWW::Selenium) seems like a good place to start.

**Update:** From the comments, you'll see that a better choice is [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver).

Comment: It was updated at 2013. It is old. My testers sayd it does not work with latest Selenium.

Comment: @EugenKonkov Have you considered contacting the author to see if he has any plans to update it?

Comment: Indeed, (`Test::`)`WWW::Selenium` is for Selenium 1. Use `Selenium::Remote::Driver`.